# jQuery Validate Plugin: Set rule on a set of checkboxes if radio button is selected

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Question: I have two radio buttons; if a user selects one then a list of 3 checkboxes appear. At least one of those checkboxes must be selected. How do I translate that into an elegant rule?

The html:

```
<label><input id="optionB_radio" type="radio">Option B</label>
<input id="subOption1_cb" type="checkbox" disabled="disabled">sub option 1</label>  
<input  id="subOption2_cb" type="checkbox" disabled="disabled">sub option 2</label> 
<input id="subOption3_cb" type="checkbox" disabled="disabled">sub option 3</label>
```

What I currently have is this...but I'm hoping there's a more elegant solution.

```
subOption1_cb:
            required:{
                depends: function(el) {
                    return ($("#option1_radio:selected") && $("#subOption2:checked").length == 0 && $("#subOption3:checked").length == 0);
                }
            },
        subOption2_cb:
            required:{
                depends: function(el) {
                    return ($("#option1_radio:selected") && $("#subOption1:checked").length == 0 && $("#subOption3:checked").length == 0);
                }
            },
        subOption3_cb:
            required:{
                depends: function(el) {
                    return ($("#option1_radio:selected") && $("#subOption2:checked").length == 0 && $("#subOption1:checked").length == 0);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a bunch of issues keeping this from working properly...

- Any element considered for validation by this plugin MUST contain a `name` attribute, but you have none.  Since all the checkboxes are part of a grouping, they can share the same `name`.  Then by assigning the `required` rule to this one `name`, you will automatically require at least one checkbox out of the group.
- Your object literal is not constructed properly.  You are missing the opening/closing braces, `{}`, that surround the set of rules just after each `name`.
- Your `"#option1_radio:selected"` selector does not match the `id` of your radio element.  You also need a `:checked` selector for the radio element within the jQuery `.is()` method, not a `:select`.

  ```
  $("#optionB_radio").is(":checked")
  ```
- Remove `disabled="disabled"` or these elements will always be ignored.

`rules` object:

```
rules: {
    subOption: { // <- this MUST be the NAME attribute and include braces
        required: {
            depends: function(el) {
                return $("#optionB_radio").is(":checked");
            }
        }
    },
    // other elements
}
```

HTML:

```
<label><input id="optionB_radio" type="radio">Option B</label>

<input name="subOption" id="subOption1_cb" type="checkbox">sub option 1</label>  
<input name="subOption" id="subOption2_cb" type="checkbox">sub option 2</label> 
<input name="subOption" id="subOption3_cb" type="checkbox">sub option 3</label>
```

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/fzz7yyL6/**

Comment: In my haste to convert real code to pseudo code I made several of the mistakes you mentioned, i.e. the construction of the object literal and the use of the "selected" property. But you are right on target with the "name" attribute and it'll work perfectly. Thank you very much for your help.